# JAVA REST Web service authentification

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have a general question regarding the authentification of the users. 
Just to sum everything up: 
I have an android app, webservice and a database. I will use token authentification. 
The user will log in the app and I will create a temporary token. 
I want to check now, if a header contains a right header. 
So let me ask my question:
Do I have to check that in every methode of my webservice? Or is there a possibility to check that in general. If I have to check that in every methode, I would slow the whole service down, if I have to check the whole table.

Thanks,
Jan

Update:
Perhaps a solution: Create an user object and check the token on the login method and set it to true and use this object.

Comment: You can create a Filter in your web service intended for token authorization.

Comment: What do you mean the "the whole table"? You can use filters or whatever HTTP interceptor your webservices framework provides to check header on every request and use AOP to check for role authorization on individual methods if needed.

Comment: Firstly ensuring that every call is authenticated is the most secure way of doing things. Worrying about slow down at this point is NOT a concern. You can optimise things once they are working. As pointed out you can use filters to do the authentication every time transparently.